# How to find the expected average value of a sequence of numbers?

Tags: probability

Assume we now have a sequence of numbers $a_{i}$, $1\le i\le n$. We random pick up a sample of size $m,1<m<n$. What is the expectation value for the average of the sample? Is there any quick way to find a rough bound on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:  the average of $a_1,\ldots, a_n$.

Let  $B_1,\ldots,B_m$ be your random selection.  $E[\frac1m \sum_{i=1}^m B_i] = \frac1m \sum_{i=1}^m EB_i = \frac1m \cdot mEB_1 = EB_1$.